isometric structure alignment
I am having trouble with the structures not being placed in the correct area, and also a weird regeneration of the floor (optional to solve)
here is the code:
package main;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

class Structure {
    int x, y;
    BufferedImage image;

    public Structure(int x, int y, BufferedImage image) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.image = image;
    }
}

public class IsometricViewport extends JPanel {
    private static final int TILE_WIDTH = 512;
    private static final int TILE_HEIGHT = 256;
    private static final int char_scale_width = 128;
    private static final int char_scale_height = 128;

    private int mapX = 0;
    private int mapY = 0;

    private BufferedImage[] terrainImages;
    private Map<String, Integer[]> biomes;
    private List<Structure> structures = new ArrayList<>();
    private BufferedImage structureImage;

    public IsometricViewport() {
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setPreferredSize(screenSize);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        try {
            terrainImages = new BufferedImage[]{
                    ImageIO.read(new File("iso_grass.png")),
                    ImageIO.read(new File("iso_dirt.png")),
                    ImageIO.read(new File("iso_rock.png"))
            };
            structureImage = ImageIO.read(new File("structure.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        biomes = new HashMap<>();
        biomes.put("grassland", new Integer[]{0, 2, 1, 1});
        biomes.put("mountain", new Integer[]{1, 0, 0, 2});

        setFocusable(true);
        addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
                    case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                        mapY += 10;
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                        mapY -= 10;
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                        mapX += 10;
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                        mapX -= 10;
                        break;
                }
                repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
        });

        addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                Point isoPoint = screenToIso(e.getX(), e.getY());
                structures.add(new Structure(isoPoint.x, isoPoint.y, structureImage));
                repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        for (int x = 1; x < getWidth(); x += TILE_WIDTH / 2) {
            for (int y = 1; y < getHeight(); y += TILE_HEIGHT / 2) {
                drawIsometricTile(g, x + mapX, y + mapY);
            }
        }

        for (Structure structure : structures) {
            drawStructure(g, structure.x + mapX, structure.y + mapY);
        }

        drawCharacter(g, getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
    }

    private void drawIsometricTile(Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        int isoX = (x - y - 2) / 1;
        int isoY = (x + y * 3) / 2;

        String biome = new Random().nextBoolean() ? "grassland" : "mountain";

        Integer[] biomeTiles = biomes.get(biome);
        int tileIndex = biomeTiles[new Random().nextInt(biomeTiles.length)];

        g.drawImage(terrainImages[tileIndex], isoX, isoY, TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT, null);
    }

    private void drawStructure(Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        int isoX = (x - y - 2) / 1;
        int isoY = (x + y * 3) / 2;

        g.drawImage(structureImage, isoX, isoY, TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT, null);
    }

    private void drawCharacter(Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        int charX = (505);
        int charY = (500);

        try {
            BufferedImage character_image = ImageIO.read(new File("char_body.png"));
            g.drawImage(character_image, charX, charY, char_scale_width, char_scale_height, null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Point screenToIso(int x, int y) {
        int isoX = (x + 2 * y) / 2;
        int isoY = (2 * y - x) / 2;
        return new Point(isoX, isoY);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Isometric Viewport");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(new IsometricViewport());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}

and here is all the images I used
iso_grass.png
iso_rock.png
iso_dirt.png
iso_test.png (for testing tile alignments)
structure.png
char_body.png
I expected the structures to align with and be on top of the tile I clicked
(and for that optional piece I expected the code to generate once and stay the same)
